# ArcMap World borders overlay?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.4, borders

I'm trying to display some weather data in ArcMap 10.4.1. Starting with a blank map, I've successfully displayed the data from a GRIB file. I've figured out the lat/lon grids and those are showing. How do I add country borders to the map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using ArcMap, you can add any of the ESRI provided basemaps. most have political borders (i.e countries).

[image]

If you want to add the countries as an editable layer, you can download a world boundary data from the [GADM](http://www.gadm.org/), or [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/)

---

You can overlay a raster image over the Basemap and show the background by setting the trasparency if your data. 
Otherwise, if you want to show borders on top of your data, download the global vector layers in the links I've provided.

Comment: I guess this is where I got stuck before.  Since these are basemaps they won't be visible under my data layer.  My next move I guess is too make my data a little transparent?  Sorry this is my first rodeo with GIS.

Comment: @Jotter, the GADM and Natural Earth datasets include vector data which can be laid over your raster data